# Is it possible to make a single loop that is separated into multiple Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, file, loops, syntax

Basically, I wanted to make a long nested loop like...

```
if (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
      if (somevar == 0) {...}
      else if (somevar1 == 1) {...}
      else if (somevar2 == 2) {...}
      else if (somevar3 == 3) {...}
      else if (somevar4 == 4) {...}
      ...so on. 

      else {...}
}
```

Is it possible to put the code line of "else if" in separated javascript files especially when you plan to write long different logic and functions for each else if? Or everything has to be within the loop? It is really a matter of reading conveniences, and I am just wondering if there is any way to make this easier.

Comment: I believe you don't even need to use  many `else if` here, what are you trying to achieve at first place?

Comment: There is some javascript library with API that I like to play with, and I ended up making a really long nested loop... I just want to separate them for easier reading. The example I wrote is kind of nothing like that but I just want to know if there is a way to separate them.

Comment: I'd recommend posting a question with the _real_ code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, there are nice people there that will help you for refactoring the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do so with functions like:

```
if (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
      if (somevar == 0) {func2()}
      else if (somevar1 == 1) {func1()}
      else if (somevar2 == 2) {func2()}
}
```

Then divide the functions across files.

Comment: Appreciate it, this is what I am looking for... feeling silly.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be to define a function in `foo.js` and then call it from the file with your `if` chain.

```
  else if (somevar4 == 4) { foo(); }
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb... this is what I am trying to do.